# App crashes after updating CoreData model that is being displayed in a UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a  strange bug that is extremely rare but causes the app to crash. I can't reproduce it but I finally found a crash report documenting this.
(I posted the stack trace below. I used a screenshot, as the quotes function here messed up the formatting. That would be unreadable)

So the problem begins after tapping a button, which calls the method `closeButtonTapped`.

This method is supposed to fade out a `popup-view` (called `ExtendBitPopupView`) and save the text the user entered (`details` attribute of one of my data models).
That's the `closeButtonTapped` method:

```
func closeButtonTapped(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        fadeOut {  // fadeOut(completion:) just fades out the UI
            if self.infoTextView.text != "Enter details..." {
                self.entry.info = self.infoTextView.text
                self.appDelegate.saveContext()
            }
        }
}
```

So it takes the text the user entered and saves it as `entry.info` to the database.

Now, a little bit of context: The `ExtendBitPopupView` is a `popup` that fades in above a `UITableView` that displays all `entry` objects there are in the database. It's using a `NSFetchedResultsController` to manage the data. The table does not show the `entry.info` attribute. That is only visible inside the `ExtendBitPopupView`

According to the stack trace, the app crashes while calling the `controllerDidChange` method. I guess it calls this method because an `entry` has changed.

```
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
        switch type {
        case .insert:
            tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .automatic)
        case .delete:
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .automatic)
        case .update: // I guess this case is being used
            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! BitCell
            let entry = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath!)
            cell.configure(entry: entry)
        case .move:
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .automatic)
            tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .automatic)
        }
    }
```

Line 224 is mentioned in the crash log. It's this line:

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! BitCell
```

I can't figure out why the app could crash at this moment. Also, it does work correctly 99% of the time.

My only observation is that when it happens, I typed in quite a lot of text. But I'm not sure about this, as it only happened like 3-4 times so far.

Does anyone have any ideas? I don't know what I can try and I don't know how to reproduce this bug.
If you need any more code, let me know. I just posted the code that is mentioned in the crash log.

Thanks in advance!

[image: stack trace]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`indexPath`  is the index BEFORE the deletes and inserts are applied;  `newIndexPath` is the index AFTER the deletes and inserts are applied.

For updates you don't care where it was BEFORE the inserts and delete - only after - so use `newIndexPath` not `indexPath`. This will fix crashes that can happen when you an update and insert (or update and delete) at the same time.

For `move` the delegate is saying where it moved from BEFORE the inserts and where it should be inserted AFTER the inserts and deletes. This can be challenging when you have a move and insert (or move and delete). I fixed this by saving all the changes from `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:` into three different indexPath arrays: insert, delete and update. When you get a `move` add an entry for it in both the insert array and in the delete array. In `controllerDidChangeContent:` sort the delete array descending and the insert array ascending.  Then apply the changes  - first delete, then insert, then update.  This will fix crashes that can happens when you have a move and insert (or move and delete) at the same time.

It is the same principle for sections. Save the sections changes in arrays, and then apply the changes in order: deletes (descending), sectionDelete (descending), sectionInserts (ascending), inserts(ascending), updates (any order). Sections can't move or be updated.

Comment: I pasted the whole method from the book `CoreData by Tutorials`. They did use `indexPath`

Comment: They are wrong.  I had a simple app that generates a change to to core data every second and worked for a long time to apply the updates in a way that it never crashes.  The way you are doing it DOES have cases that will crash (even with changing it to newIndexPath), but that is an involved answer and it seems like you just want a simple fix.

Comment: Can you explain why using `newIndexPath` is causing no/less crashes? Edit: I never said I want a simple fix, I just want the app to not crash :D

Comment: Okay, I think I get the point. I will try to implement this. Thanks for taking time to explain this! I guess this could be considered as the correct answer as it probably will solve the cause of my problem