# Table View not loading after deleting or inserting core data

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3

I am using core data to store events into an agenda app I am making. I have a segment controller that allows the app to sort via date or tags. When I add or delete an event to the table view, nothing is changing in the view and the segment bar breaks, nothin happens. However, I when I restart the app, all the elements are sorted, the segment bar works and all elements are there. Its just when I add or delete elements where it breaks.

heres the code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class MainVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,         UITableViewDataSource, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var segControl: UISegmentedControl!

    var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Event>!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        attemptFetchRequest()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        attemptFetchRequest()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "eventCell", for: indexPath) as? EventCell {
            configureCell(cell: cell, indexPath: indexPath as NSIndexPath)
            return cell
        }
        return EventCell()
    }

    //calling configure cell in this VC too

    func configureCell(cell: EventCell, indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let event = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath as IndexPath)
        cell.configureCell(event: event)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let events = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects , events.count > 0 {
            let event = events[indexPath.row]
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "DetailsVC", sender: event)
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "DetailsVC" {
            if let dest = segue.destination as? DetailsVC {
                if let event = sender as? Event {
                    dest.eventToEdit = event
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        if let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections {
            return sections.count
        }
        return 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections {
            let sectionInfo = sections[section]
            return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
        }
        return 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?{ 
        if let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections {
            let currentSection = sections[section]
            return currentSection.name
        }
    return nil
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 126
    }

    func attemptFetchRequest() {
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Event> = Event.fetchRequest()
        let dateSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false) //sort by date
        let tagSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "tag", ascending: false) //sort by tag
        var key: String!
        if segControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            key = "date"
            fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [dateSort]
        } else {
            key = "tag"
            fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [tagSort]
        }
        let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: key, cacheName: nil)
        controller.delegate = self
        self.fetchedResultsController = controller
        do {
            try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        } catch {
            let err = error as NSError
            print("\(err)")
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        //tableView.beginUpdates()
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        tableView.reloadData()
        //tableView.endUpdates()
    }

    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
        switch(type) {
        case.insert:
            if let indexPath = newIndexPath {
                tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            }
            break
        case.delete:
            if let indexPath = indexPath {
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            }
            break
        case.update:
            if let indexPath = newIndexPath {
                if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? EventCell {
                    configureCell(cell: cell, indexPath: indexPath as NSIndexPath)
                }
            }
            break
        case.move:
            if let indexPath = indexPath {
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            }
            if let indexPath = newIndexPath {
                tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            }
            break
        }
    }

    @IBAction func segControllerChanged(_ sender: Any) {
        attemptFetchRequest()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Heres my other VC

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class DetailsVC: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var titleTextField: CustomTextField!

@IBOutlet weak var locationTextField: CustomTextField!

@IBOutlet weak var DescTextField: CustomTextField!

@IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

@IBOutlet weak var tagPicker: UIPickerView!

private var _tags = ["Meeting", "Breakfast/Lunch/Dinner", "Appointment", "Other"]

var tags: [String] {
    return _tags
}

var eventToEdit: Event?

var imgPicker: UIImagePickerController!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    titleTextField.delegate = self
    locationTextField.delegate = self
    DescTextField.delegate = self

    tagPicker.delegate = self
    tagPicker.dataSource = self

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, YYYY H:mm a"

    if eventToEdit != nil {
        loadEventData()
    }

    imgPicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imgPicker.delegate = self

}

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    let tag = _tags[row]
    return tag

}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return _tags.count
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1

}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    //do something

}

@IBAction func saveBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    var event: Event! //guarenteed to have Event
    let pic = Image(context: context)
    pic.image = image.image

    if eventToEdit == nil {
        event = Event(context: context)
    } else {
        event = eventToEdit
    }

    if let title = titleTextField.text {
        event.title = title
    }

    if let location = locationTextField.text {
        event.location = location
    }

    if let desc = DescTextField.text {
        event.detail = desc
    }

    event.toImage = pic

    event.tag = _tags[tagPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]


    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, YYYY HH:mm"
    event.fullDate = datePicker.date as NSDate?


    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, YYYY"
    event.date = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
    event.time = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)

    ad.saveContext()

    _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}

func loadEventData() {

    if let event = eventToEdit {
        titleTextField.text = event.title
        locationTextField.text = event.location
        DescTextField.text = event.detail
        image.image = event.toImage?.image as? UIImage

        if let tag = event.tag {

            var i = 0
            repeat {

                let t = _tags[i]
                if t == tag {
                    tagPicker.selectRow(i, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
                }

                i += 1
            } while (i < _tags.count)
        }
    }

}

@IBAction func deleteBtnPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    if eventToEdit != nil {
        context.delete(eventToEdit!)
        ad.saveContext()
    }

    _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}


@IBAction func imgBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    present(imgPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    if let img = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        image.image = img
    }
    imgPicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    titleTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    locationTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    DescTextField.resignFirstResponder()

    return true
}
```

}

thanks!

Comment: Your deadlines are not Stack Overflow's responsibility.

Comment: @matt my bad, just nervous..

Comment: You say "When I add or delete an event to the table view". But I don't see any code where that happens. I see that you are configured to respond if it _does_ happen, but I don't see any reason why it _would_ happen. For that to happen, I would need see you e.g. make a new entity object and save the context, and that never happens (in fact, you never save your context at all).

Comment: @JasonP I will consider to answer your future question when you learn to give feedback on the answers you get from people spending their free time trying to help you, before you create new questions.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are getting a waring in the console along the lines of `The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (0) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (0), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted).`  After you get the error a tableview will no longer do any updates.

These error can occur when you do not update the tableview correctly in response to the fetchedResultsController delegate events.  You can test if that is the issue by replacing your implementation of `controllerDidChangeContent` with tableview.reloadData() and removing everything you are doing in `controllerWillChangeContent` `controllerDidChange`.  Unfortunately Apple's example code for updating a tableview from a fetchedResultsController is wrong and will not deal with all situations.  see my answer here: [App crashes after updating CoreData model that is being displayed in a UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41789817/app-crashes-after-updating-coredata-model-that-is-being-displayed-in-a-uitablevi/41790552#41790552) for a full explanation on how to fix it. But if you are lazy and just want it to work you can simply do `reloadData`.

Comment: for the "quick" fix, in my     'controllerDidChangeContent'    , I deleted everything and simply wrote tableview.reloadData() and have no implementation for 'controllerWillChange', however, my app is still crashing when trying to insert more than 1 item or deleting more than 1 item.. Also, I read you solution, and I tried change indexPath to newIndexPath in my "update", however, my app is still crashing when I insert and delete.. super confused..

Comment: If removing everything except for reloadData doesn't fix it then you have a different problem then the one that I thought.  Do you have any warning printed in the console?

Comment: I edited my original post and you can see my previous implementation of my controllerDidChange and controllerWillChange that is commented it out. When I used reloadData(), I get "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException" when i try to insert, update, or remove cells (although removing sometimes works flawlessly, I'm not sure why). However, with my original implementation of  controllerDidChange and controllerWillChange, I would get the error you mentioned above.

Comment: try also commenting out    `controller(_:​did​Change:​at:​for:​new​Index​Path:​)`

Comment: that seemed to have fixed the crashing, but can you explain why it works? This seems like a very "hacky" way of fixing it, do you have any idea how to fix it while implementing all the proper functions?  Thank you by the way

Edit: It seems now that even though inserting and deleting works, when ever I click on a cell, it always shows me the first cell.

Comment: Yes it is hacky - but it does diagnose the problem. The correct solution is implement the delegates of a fetchedResultsController correctly which can be very tricky.  I have linked to an answer where I explain fully how I accomplished this.

Comment: The reason you are getting the wrong row on selection is because of the line `if let events = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects ` which will only work if you have only one section. You should use `event = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath as IndexPath)`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me! I really appreciate it.