# NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate returning wrong NSFetchedResultsChangeType

Tags: swift, core-data, xcode8

Here is my implementation of the delegate:

```
func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    ItemListTableViewController.logger.log("begin updates")
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView.endUpdates()
    ItemListTableViewController.logger.log("end updates")
}

func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
    ItemListTableViewController.logger.log(type.rawValue, "\(indexPath) -> \(newIndexPath)")
    switch type {
    case .delete:
        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .automatic)
    case .insert:
        self.tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .automatic)
    case .move:
        self.tableView.moveRow(at: indexPath!, to: newIndexPath!)
    case .update:
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

And here are the log I got:

```
ItemListTableViewController >>> "perform insert start" 
ItemListTableViewController >>> "begin updates" 
ItemListTableViewController >>> 1 "nil -> Optional([0, 0])" 
ItemListTableViewController >>> 4 "Optional([0, 1]) -> Optional([0, 2])"
ItemListTableViewController >>> "end updates" 
ItemListTableViewController >>> "perform insert end"
```

I'm trying to insert a new item into the context by calling `context.insert(item)`, and a new item inserted according to the 3rd line of log. And the controller moves some item according to the 4th line. But the type of raw value '4' in `NSFetchedResultsChangeType` should be `update` but not `move`.

<s>I also have tested for other cases, when I need to update an item, it gave me a `move` type.




Am I wrong about the meaning of the `update` and the `move`? Or it's a bug?</s>

I was wrong. It was a bad code.

I'm using Xcode 8.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4 is the enum value for `update`; 3 is the value for `move`.  You may be confused by the two index paths that are being delegated.  `indexPath` is the index before the update (before any inserts or deletes) and `newIndexPath` is the index after the updates.  Unfortunately Apple's documentation is wrong when it come to how to update using a fetchedResults controller.  For update you should be using `newIndexPath` since the updates are processed after the inserts and deletes.    You may be experiencing crashes or bad behavior because of this.

Also the way you are dealing with move is incorrect.  See [App crashes after updating CoreData model that is being displayed in a UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41789817/app-crashes-after-updating-coredata-model-that-is-being-displayed-in-a-uitablevi/41790552#41790552)

Comment: I have add some context code in question. So, I need to just reload newIndex for type `update`? And I am still confusing with `move`. Isn't that designed for `moveRow(at: to)`?

Comment: You'd think that a `NSFetchedResultsChangeTypeMove` could translate into a `moveRow(at: to)`.  And that is also what Apple docs say to do. By sadly they are wrong.  The problem is that the `indexPath` is the index before the inserts and deletes and `newIndexPath` is after the inserts and deletes.  So if you had [B, C, D] and B moved and A was inserted to be [A, C, B, D], you would get `insert` (0,0) and `move` (0,0)->(0,2) (NOT (0,1)-(0,2) as you would expect).  So if you tried to called `moveRow(at: to)` using indexPath and `newIndexPath` you would end up moving A not B.

Comment: That is what I'm confusing. So I should compute every index by myself? I need to record every insertion and deletion before, and make an offset for current index?

Comment: I see, in `insert`/`delete`/`update`, the indexPath is not useful, so I just need to calculate in the `move` case.

Comment: for `delete` use `indexPath`; for `insert` and `update` use `newIndexPath`. I have a full answer on how to make a tableView or collectionView never crash from fetched results controller updates which I linked to in my answer above.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for your patience, I'm trying to correct my codes.

Answer (score 2):

Thank to @Joe Rose, I understand how this works. I'm not dealing with tasks that may insert and move in same time, so I didn't use your solution.

I was wrong about what `update` and  `move` means. So I read Apple's doc again. It said:

> Changes are reported with the following heuristics:
>
> - On add and remove operations, only the added/removed object is reported.
>
>   It’s assumed that all objects that come after the affected object are also moved, but these moves are not reported.
> - A move is reported when the changed attribute on the object is one of the sort descriptors used in the fetch request.
>
>   An update of the object is assumed in this case, but no separate update message is sent to the delegate.
> - An update is reported when an object’s state changes, but the changed attributes aren’t part of the sort keys.

So when `move` is reported, `update` is reported too. At that time, the fetched objects are updated, but tableView not, so I need to use `indexPath` to locate the cell, and `newIndexPath` to get the proper object.

This is my final solution and it behaves good for now:

```
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
    ItemListTableViewController.logger.log(type.rawValue, "\(indexPath) -> \(newIndexPath)")

    switch type {
    case .insert:
        self.tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .automatic)
    case .delete:
        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .automatic)
    case .move:
        self.tableView.moveRow(at: indexPath!, to: newIndexPath!)
        fallthrough
    case .update:
        self.configure(cell: tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! ItemInfoCell, at: newIndexPath!)
    }
}


func configure(cell: ItemInfoCell, at indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let item = fetchController.object(at: indexPath)
    cell.item = item
}
```

If there is any problem, please tell me.

Comment: In the update case, you could just `anObject` already passed in the method parameter, instead of having to `fetchController.object(at: indexPath)`

Comment: If the cell for the updated object is not on the screen then cellForRow will return nil and your as! will crash. You need to do if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(..) { configure(..) }