# How to know the fetchRequest data is ready?

Tags: swift, core-data, uicollectionview

I tried many weeks to solve this problem.

My data doesn't ready before another view present.

Here is my code

FirstViewController.swift

```
let moc = DatabaseController.getContext()

moc.performAndWait {
   let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<Pet> = Pet.fetchRequest()
   fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = true
   fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "order", ascending: false,selector: #selector(NSString.localizedStandardCompare(_:)))]

   self.petObj= try! fetchRequest.execute()
}

let VC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
VC.petObj = self.petObj

let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC)
navController.navigationBar.isHidden = true
self.present(navController, animated:true, completion: nil)
```

[image: Click here to see my second view result]

as the result above you will see wrong and right output

I solved the problem by adding

```
sleep(1)
```

before ending of performAndWait but I know this is not the right way to handle this problem.

So my investigate is the fetch data is not ready.

Answer (score 0):

Use a fetchedResultsController.  A fetchedResultsController does a fetch and then monitors core data for any changes (updates, deletes, inserts, moves) to tells your UI to update.  In general I like to always use fetchedResultsController and never just do a fetch.  Here are some reasons:

1. A fetchedResultsController will keep your view in sync with what is in core-data.  So you rarely have out of date information being displayed.  As writing in core data is often done is a background thread this is a common issue.
2. Accessing a core-data object after it has been deleted will cause a crash.  ManagedObjects are not like normal objects, a strong pointer is not enough to guarantee that they will be in memory.  If the entity is deleted from the store accessing the object will cause a crash. FetchedResultsController monitors for deletion so the `fetchedObjects` property is always safe to access
3. They are cheap and easy.  Don't be afraid to use them even for just one object.  They do not take up a lot of resources.
4. They work great with collectionViews and tableViews.  They are setup to have indexPaths to match your collectionView or tableViews.  But you aren't required to use them.  They can be matched up to any view.  Just make sure to update them as need when the delegate tells you to.

There are however a few issue to look out for:

1. They will not update if related objects are changed.  So if you fetching all `students` that are in a special class `ANY class.special == 1` it will not update if the class object updates since it is only looking at the student objects
2. Updating a tableview or collectionView correctly can be tricky.  Because of the way moves are dealt with is can be hard to update the view correct.  see my answer here: [App crashes after updating CoreData model that is being displayed in a UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41789817/app-crashes-after-updating-coredata-model-that-is-being-displayed-in-a-uitablevi/41790552#41790552)

Hope that helps