# I want a generic fetchedResultController for CoreData to support multiple models

Tags: ios, swift, generics, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have simplified my problem to make the question easier, so hopefully the code I am posting is sufficient.

My goal is to use one class that can support multiple models from CoreData so that I can avoid recreating the same stuff for each class.

```
class FRC<T> where T: NSManagedObject {
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext

    fileprivate lazy var fetchedResultscontroller: NSFetchedResultsController<T> = { [weak self] in
        guard let this = self else {
            fatalError("lazy property has been called after object has been descructed")
        }
        guard let request = T.fetchRequest() as? NSFetchRequest<T> else {
            fatalError("Can't set up NSFetchRequest")
        }
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "key", ascending: true)]
        return NSFetchedResultsController<T>(fetchRequest: request,
                                             managedObjectContext: this.context,
                                             sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
                                             cacheName: nil)
        }()

    init(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        self.context = context
    }
}

enum ModelType {
    case modelA
    case modelB
}

class GenericDataModel: NSObject {
    let container: NSPersistentContainer
    // STUPID!!!
    var frcA: FRC<ModelA>?
    var frcB: FRC<ModelB>?

    init(modelType: ModelType) {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyContainer")
        container.loadPersistentStores { _, error in /* Handle */ }
        // Below here is ugly!
        switch modelType {
        case .modelA:
            frcA = FRC<ModelA>(context: container.viewContext)
        case .modelB:
            frcB = FRC<ModelB>(context: container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}

extension GenericDataModel: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>,
                    didChange anObject: Any,
                    at indexPath: IndexPath?,
                    for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType,
                    newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
        // Handle
    }
}
```

It seems that the best I can do is to make multiple variables in my GenericDataModel class for different model classes, which will not scale well for a large number of them.

However, trying to make a single local variable for the FRC class keeps failing and I cannot understand why.

I am new to generics, so it is likely I am just doing something stupid.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bad idea.  I already did it:
https://github.com/jon513/FetchedResultsControllerNeverCrash/blob/master/coreDataNeverCrash/FetchedResultsControllerManager.swift

This implements a method to have core data never crash when getting a delete and update at the same time (see [App crashes after updating CoreData model that is being displayed in a UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41789817/app-crashes-after-updating-coredata-model-that-is-being-displayed-in-a-uitablevi/41790552#41790552)), as well as making the api a little easier.

To use it create a FetchedResultsControllerManager with fetchRequest, context and a delegate.

The delegate implementation is easy:

```
extension ViewController : FetchedResultsControllerManagerDelegate {
    func managerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSObject, change: FetchedResultsControllerManagerChange) {
        change.applyChanges(collectionView: collectionView)
    }
}
```

I couldn't get the delegate's to return the correct class because of the generics stuff, but I never had to test to anything other than equally so it never bothered me. If you can get it work with generics I would love to get a pull request.